# Why does my input current inverter is high?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, opto-isolator, boost, buck-boost

[image]

I have a problem with input current in my inverter is high. My inverter will use for solar panel and using boost converter to convert dc voltage 12-18 Volt to 24 volt. I'm using P channel mosfet IRF9540 and N channel mosfer IRF540 as switching to convert dc to ac and using optocoupler pc817 as driver mosfet. And i use sine pulse width modulation arduino program. So the problem is when i give input voltage less than 12 volt, the input current is high 5 ampere. Is there something wrong in my inverter circuit?

Comment: where is the high current flowing in that circuit?

Comment: High currents occur in the DC supply voltage, so the boost and mosfet burn

Comment: You've got slow optocouplers driving half-bridges, you're probably getting a lot of shoot-through current. What value are R1/R5?

Comment: How should I choose the optocoupler that is suitable for my circuit? Do you have suggestions for optocoupler? The value of R1 / R5 is 1k ohms

Comment: Logic output optocoupler and consider adding dead time between driving high and low.

Comment: First you didn't mention the output current. If it's above 2A@24V, 5A@12V isn't all that bad.

Comment: the output current is 24V 5A